# Can I rotate cache expiration in a Redis cluster

Tags: redis

I have a redis cluster with several replica nodes, holding a cache of a time-consuming complex db query. The cache expires every minute, and lately with enough traffic volume I've had client timeouts while the cache is rebuilding and waiting for that complex db query to complete.

What I'd like to do is set it up so one node expires every even minute while the other expires every odd minute, this way if one node is rebuilding the cache, the other node can serve the cache. Does Redis have such a feature, or is there a recommended workaround for a scenario like this? I couldn't find any docs on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Redis cluster, the primary will expire the key and instruct its replicas to expire it too by issuing a `DEL` command to them on the cluster bus.

If you want the value to be always available for your clients, then you need to a process to refresh your key at the cadence you want and then use the expiration cache-miss scenario as a failback in case the refresh process failed.

If you really want to use two keys and have them expire every other minute, you can use [`EXPIREAT`](https://redis.io/commands/EXPIREAT) or its precise version [`PEXPIREAT`](https://redis.io/commands/PEXPIREAT). But this sounds unnecessary.

You can use [`TTL`](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) (or [`PTTL`](https://redis.io/commands/pttl)) to consult on the time left for a key.

If your clients access the cache key on bursts and you just want to avoid some of them getting a cache-miss every minute and therefore timing out, you can get the value and the TTL and if it is lower than a reasonable time you then trigger the query to refresh after responding to your client immediately.

You can use a simple [Lua Script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) so you query both the value and the TTL of the key with one request to the Redis server. You can also do the same with [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) or [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions), I just like to promote Lua scripting as it is a more powerful tool.

```
local val = {} 
val[1] = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]) 
if val[1] then
    val[2] = redis.call('PTTL', KEYS[1]) 
    return val
else
    return false
end
```

You use as

```
EVAL "local val = {} val[1] = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]) if val[1] then  val[2] = redis.call('PTTL', KEYS[1]) return val else return false end" 1 data
1) "queryResult"
2) (integer) 1664
```

You get both the value and the TTL and then you can trigger a proactive refresh if your cache key is close to expire.